# Django Division in models return integer only

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

good morning,

Trying to do a weighted average with some values in my models.

```
    def get_resultavg(self):
            return Result.objects.filter(employee_id=self, eval_at__isnull=False).exclude(evaluation_value=0).aggregate(average=Sum(F('evaluation_value')*F('question__question_weight')/100, output_field=FloatField()))
```

and In my template

```
    <td class="text-center align-middle">{% with averagecalc=employee.get_resultavg %}
        {% if averagecalc %}
                      <small>
                          {{ averagecalc.average|floatformat:"-2"|default:"-" }}
                        </a>
                      </small>

          {% endif %}
                    {% endwith %}</td>
```

The result in template should be 4.2 based on numbers for question_weight and evaluation_value.

But it brings me 4.00, I know the problem is when I include the division. I tried with float(100), mutiplying * 0.01 but nothing.

What am I doing wrong here guys?

Thanks

Comment: Which database backend are You using?

Comment: Sql server with pyodb azure

Comment: Thank you, solved using Cast function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using

```
    from django.db.models.functions import Cast


    def get_resultavg(self):

    return Result.objects.filter(employee_id=self, eval_at__isnull=False).exclude(evaluation_value=0).aggregate(average=Sum(Cast(F('evaluation_value')*F('question__question_weight')/100, output_field=FloatField())))
```